# Deleting Certain Extension with Bash (quickly)

Tags: python, bash, rm

I have seen other threads about deleting a certain extension in a directory.  However, when I try it, it seems to work but takes a long time to go through directories and say "Permission denied" on the system ones.  All I want is  a bash script that goes through the entire computer, or part of it, and deletes a certain extension.  If python would be faster that is fine.

Comment: would it be dangerous if it is just deleting a certain extension... what could go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by extension? Like, a Python module?

Comment: [What are you really trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: I mean a file extension.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use find I guess.

```
find / -name "*.myextension" -exec rm {} \;
```

But of course, searching a whole HDD (or partition..) from / is a long thing to do, and you will get **permission denied** errors as long as you're not running this as root.

Comment: Would python be faster?

Comment: Because it's a fork for every single `rm`. You should either use `-exec rm -- {} +`, or the GNU find `-delete`.

Comment: Or pipe find output into `xargs rm`, making suitable effort to handle filenames with whitespace

Comment: @glennjackman May you please exactly what command to use for doing the same thing but making it work with spaces? Where would I put xargs rm?

Answer (score 1):

using xargs, assuming you have GNU find and xargs:

```
find / -name \*.myextension -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This method uses the null char `\0` as the separator between filenames: since newline is a legal character in a filename, reading find's output line-by-line is not 100% safe.

Comment: It says 
`file: invalid option -- a
file: invalid option -- t
Usage: file [-bchikLNnprsvz0] [-e test] [-f namefile] [-F separator] [-m magicfiles] [-M magicfiles] file...
       file -C -m magicfiles
Try `file --help' for more information.`

Comment: I am on a Mac, could that be the problem?

Comment: No, typo, should be `find` not `file`

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you, but I named a file "with spaces.myextension" and put it on the desktop.  I then did the command `find /users/<myusername>/Desktop -name \*.myextension -print0 | xargs -0 rm` and the file remained there.

Comment: Do you see it with `find /users/<myusername>/Desktop -name \*.myextension -print` ?

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: I can only conclude that you have no files with that extension, spaces or not.